# Automating lines between existing points within polygons

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, line, os-mastermap

I have a task that I do on a regular basis and was looking for a bit of assisting learning the best way to tackle automation on this.

**Brief**

- Each blue point has to be connected to the orange point with a line. (These will always be within polygon areas with 1-40 blue points to a orange point)
- Lines should stick to pathway as much as they can but can also cross other terrain if it's required (such as grass/roads).

**Resources**

I use OS Master Maps, for the surface types, QGIS 3.28, Blue + Orange points / Polygon areas are manually inserted before this line process takes place.

**Ideas**

So my initial idea to tackle this task was using some sort of least cost route process (Never done this before) Is it even possible to use least cost along side OS Master Maps?

Potentially using some sort of mesh overlay so say for example you would turn the path way into mesh, and find the best route between the points on the mesh (If it was even possible I'm assuming it would not be very efficient)

Anything to point me in the right direction would be good.

**Before**
[image: Before]

**Desired Outcome**
[image: Desired Outcome]

**Snippet of data being used/produced currently**
[Example Project](https://easyupload.io/4o2dfn)

**Update #1**
Attempted to use the least cost path option on quite an easy area that is connected purely by paths so dont have to worry about road crossing. Output is not bad how ever abit too "jagged" to be effective, its taking some odd routes thats probably the "best" but in theory when you're digging its just not practical.

**Image of Least Cost Path Attmept**
[image: Image of Least Cost Path Attempt]

**Image of Least Cost Path attempt** *(Zoomed in to show weird routing)*
[image: Zoomed Image of Least Cost Path Attempt]

Comment: Hello Bera, looking for the project files or just image of the actual data. (its for a utility network) I could do either just want to be sure I give you the correct thing.

Comment: Understood, I've added a hyperlink at the bottom of the page I've broke down a project to give you a real life example of one of the polygon areas, I've put the hand drawing tubes in there too so you can see how I've done it manually. Hopefully it looks okay any issues let me know please.